# Kettle Spoon Database connection file already in use

Tags: integration, kettle, spoon

I've created a job in Kettle Spoon, which includes transformations. 
When I execute the job, it stops at the first transformation and gives the following error message:

```
 Source T_PRPMS.0 - [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not use '(unknown)'; file already in use.
```

Comment: can you explain more on this ??? are you using any database connection ?? it looks like the database driver is not available. it would be helpful if you can share the kettle !!!

Comment: Please post more context for that error. That line alone isn't enough to understand the cause.